# How to get the penultimate result in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get the penultimate result in a query, but I cant figure out how to do that.

I have a code that actually gets the last row:

```
 (select sja.descricao
          from ldesk.jur_andamento sja
         where sja.id_andamento =
               (select max(id_andamento)
                  from ldesk.jur_andamento sja2
                 where sja2.id_assunto = a1.id_assunto
                   and data_inclusao in
                       (select max(data_inclusao)
                          from ldesk.jur_andamento sja2
                         where sja2.id_assunto = a1.id_assunto
                           and data in
                               (select max(data)
                                  from ldesk.jur_andamento
                                 where id_assunto = a1.id_assunto)))) ult_andamento_descr
```

In this code I get the last result (descricao column) from the jur_andamento table, is there a way to get the penultimate result?

Comment: A [mcve] would make this much clearer.

Comment: One common approach is to get the last result (as you supposedly have here; call it LAST) and use it in a bigger query to find the last result that *isn't* LAST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `DENSE_RANK` analytic function. So, if you are trying to find, for each `id_assunto`, the second ranked greatest rows sorted by `data` then `data_inclusao` and then `id_andamento` then you could use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT j.*,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (
           PARTITION BY id_assunto
           ORDER BY data DESC, data_inclusao DESC, id_andamento DESC
         ) AS rnk
  FROM   ldesk.jur_andamento j
)
WHERE rnk = 2;
```

If you want the maximum `data` and then `data_inclusao` values and then the second highest `id_andamento` you can filter in 2 steps:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (
           PARTITION BY id_assunto
           ORDER BY id_andamento DESC
         ) AS id_rnk
  FROM   (
    SELECT j.*,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (
             PARTITION BY id_assunto
             ORDER BY data DESC, data_inclusao DESC
           ) AS data_rnk
    FROM   ldesk.jur_andamento j
  ) t
  WHERE  data_rnk = 1
)
WHERE  id_rnk = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of Max xou can usse the window function ROW_NUMBER to get the second row, or any other for that matter

```
select sja.descricao
          from ldesk.jur_andamento sja
         where sja.id_andamento =
  (SELECT id_andamento FROM
               (select id_andamento, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id_assunto ORDER BY id_andamento DESC) rn
                from ldesk.jur_andamento sja2
                 where sja2.id_assunto = a1.id_assunto
                   and data_inclusao in
                       (select max(data_inclusao)
                          from ldesk.jur_andamento sja2
                         where sja2.id_assunto = a1.id_assunto
                           and data in
                               (select max(data)
                                  from ldesk.jur_andamento
                                 where id_assunto = a1.id_assunto)
                      )
                 
                ) andamento
  WHERE rn = 2)
```

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XcwuU46J)

Answer (score 0):

First, as mentioned earlier, you should rewrite the code appropriately to use the ORDER BY clause. The second-to-last maximum value is equivalent to the second minimum value.

Then, the appropriate function to perform this type of task is row_number().

```plsql
(SELECT descricao
   FROM (SELECT sja.descricao,
                row_number() over(ORDER BY sja.data, sja.data_inclusao, sja.id_andamento) rn
           FROM ldesk.jur_andamento sja)
  WHERE rn = 2) ult_andamento_descr
```

However, it is also possible to use OFFSET:

```sql
(SELECT descricao FROM ldesk.jur_andamento sja
  ORDER BY sja.data, sja.data_inclusao, sja.id_andamento
  OFFSET 1 rows FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY) ult_andamento_descr
```